# How to optimise this MySQL query? Millions of Rows

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, amazon-rds, sql-optimization

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    analytics.source AS referrer, 
    COUNT(analytics.id) AS frequency, 
    SUM(IF(transactions.status = 'COMPLETED', 1, 0)) AS sales
FROM analytics
LEFT JOIN transactions ON analytics.id = transactions.analytics
WHERE analytics.user_id = 52094 
GROUP BY analytics.source 
ORDER BY frequency DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

The analytics table has 60M rows and the transactions table has 3M rows.

When I run an `EXPLAIN` on this query, I get:

```
+------+--------------+-----------------+--------+---------------------+-------------------+----------------------+---------------------------+----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------+
| # id |  select_type |      table      |  type  |    possible_keys    |        key        |        key_len       |            ref            |   rows   |   Extra   |                                                 |
+------+--------------+-----------------+--------+---------------------+-------------------+----------------------+---------------------------+----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------+
| '1'  |  'SIMPLE'    |  'analytics'    |  'ref' |  'analytics_user_id | analytics_source' |  'analytics_user_id' |  '5'                      |  'const' |  '337662' |  'Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort' |
| '1'  |  'SIMPLE'    |  'transactions' |  'ref' |  'tran_analytics'   |  'tran_analytics' |  '5'                 |  'dijishop2.analytics.id' |  '1'     |  NULL     |                                                 |
+------+--------------+-----------------+--------+---------------------+-------------------+----------------------+---------------------------+----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

I can't figure out how to optimise this query as it's already very basic. It takes around 70 seconds to run this query.

Here are the indexes that exist:

```
+-------------+-------------+----------------------------+---------------+------------------+------------+--------------+-----------+---------+--------+-------------+----------+----------------+
|   # Table   |  Non_unique |          Key_name          |  Seq_in_index |    Column_name   |  Collation |  Cardinality |  Sub_part |  Packed |  Null  |  Index_type |  Comment |  Index_comment |
+-------------+-------------+----------------------------+---------------+------------------+------------+--------------+-----------+---------+--------+-------------+----------+----------------+
| 'analytics' |  '0'        |  'PRIMARY'                 |  '1'          |  'id'            |  'A'       |  '56934235'  |  NULL     |  NULL   |  ''    |  'BTREE'    |  ''      |  ''            |
| 'analytics' |  '1'        |  'analytics_user_id'       |  '1'          |  'user_id'       |  'A'       |  '130583'    |  NULL     |  NULL   |  'YES' |  'BTREE'    |  ''      |  ''            |
| 'analytics' |  '1'        |  'analytics_product_id'    |  '1'          |  'product_id'    |  'A'       |  '490812'    |  NULL     |  NULL   |  'YES' |  'BTREE'    |  ''      |  ''            |
| 'analytics' |  '1'        |  'analytics_affil_user_id' |  '1'          |  'affil_user_id' |  'A'       |  '55222'     |  NULL     |  NULL   |  'YES' |  'BTREE'    |  ''      |  ''            |
| 'analytics' |  '1'        |  'analytics_source'        |  '1'          |  'source'        |  'A'       |  '24604'     |  NULL     |  NULL   |  'YES' |  'BTREE'    |  ''      |  ''            |
| 'analytics' |  '1'        |  'analytics_country_name'  |  '1'          |  'country_name'  |  'A'       |  '39510'     |  NULL     |  NULL   |  'YES' |  'BTREE'    |  ''      |  ''            |
| 'analytics' |  '1'        |  'analytics_gordon'        |  '1'          |  'id'            |  'A'       |  '56934235'  |  NULL     |  NULL   |  ''    |  'BTREE'    |  ''      |  ''            |
| 'analytics' |  '1'        |  'analytics_gordon'        |  '2'          |  'user_id'       |  'A'       |  '56934235'  |  NULL     |  NULL   |  'YES' |  'BTREE'    |  ''      |  ''            |
| 'analytics' |  '1'        |  'analytics_gordon'        |  '3'          |  'source'        |  'A'       |  '56934235'  |  NULL     |  NULL   |  'YES' |  'BTREE'    |  ''      |  ''            |
+-------------+-------------+----------------------------+---------------+------------------+------------+--------------+-----------+---------+--------+-------------+----------+----------------+


+----------------+-------------+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+------------+--------------+-----------+---------+--------+-------------+----------+----------------+
|    # Table     |  Non_unique |      Key_name     |  Seq_in_index |    Column_name    |  Collation |  Cardinality |  Sub_part |  Packed |  Null  |  Index_type |  Comment |  Index_comment |
+----------------+-------------+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+------------+--------------+-----------+---------+--------+-------------+----------+----------------+
| 'transactions' |  '0'        |  'PRIMARY'        |  '1'          |  'id'             |  'A'       |  '2436151'   |  NULL     |  NULL   |  ''    |  'BTREE'    |  ''      |  ''            |
| 'transactions' |  '1'        |  'tran_user_id'   |  '1'          |  'user_id'        |  'A'       |  '56654'     |  NULL     |  NULL   |  ''    |  'BTREE'    |  ''      |  ''            |
| 'transactions' |  '1'        |  'transaction_id' |  '1'          |  'transaction_id' |  'A'       |  '2436151'   |  '191'    |  NULL   |  'YES' |  'BTREE'    |  ''      |  ''            |
| 'transactions' |  '1'        |  'tran_analytics' |  '1'          |  'analytics'      |  'A'       |  '2436151'   |  NULL     |  NULL   |  'YES' |  'BTREE'    |  ''      |  ''            |
| 'transactions' |  '1'        |  'tran_status'    |  '1'          |  'status'         |  'A'       |  '22'        |  NULL     |  NULL   |  'YES' |  'BTREE'    |  ''      |  ''            |
| 'transactions' |  '1'        |  'gordon_trans'   |  '1'          |  'status'         |  'A'       |  '22'        |  NULL     |  NULL   |  'YES' |  'BTREE'    |  ''      |  ''            |
| 'transactions' |  '1'        |  'gordon_trans'   |  '2'          |  'analytics'      |  'A'       |  '2436151'   |  NULL     |  NULL   |  'YES' |  'BTREE'    |  ''      |  ''            |
+----------------+-------------+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+------------+--------------+-----------+---------+--------+-------------+----------+----------------+
```

Simplified schema for the two tables before adding any extra indexes as suggested as it didn't improve the situation.

```
CREATE TABLE `analytics` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `affil_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `medium` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `terms` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_browser` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_mobile` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_robot` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `browser` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `robot` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `platform` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `referrer` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `domain` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `continent_code` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `analytics_user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `analytics_product_id` (`product_id`),
  KEY `analytics_affil_user_id` (`affil_user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=64821325 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `transaction_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pay_key` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sender_email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `analytics` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(46) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `session_id` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `eu_vat_applied` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `tran_user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `transaction_id` (`transaction_id`(191)),
  KEY `tran_analytics` (`analytics`),
  KEY `tran_status` (`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10019356 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

If the above can not be optimised any further. Any implementation advice on summary tables will be great. We are using a LAMP stack on AWS. The above query is running on RDS (m1.large).

Comment: You have a high reputation score, so you're not a newbie. You should know by now that you should include the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each of the tables in your query, so we can see what data types, indexes, and constraints you have in your tables. Help us help you!

Comment: Apologies Bill, they are massive tables (lots of columns). Will get that after I try Gordon's suggestion.

Comment: But only a few columns are referenced in your query above. You could show a reduced CREATE TABLE with only the relevant columns, with any indexes on those columns.

Comment: I've updated question to show the existing indexes.

Comment: This query is using temp tables, that could be the source of part of your problem.
It is also breaking the sort into memory manageable chuncks, because the index is too large to fit in ram at once.
How many disks is your database stored on? You may be bumping up against IO drain here. You may not get more performance than this until you change the Disk layout.
Store one table on one disk, the second on a second, and use a third for temp space. Once each table is on its own device with its own IO channel, this query should run very quickly.

Comment: The reason I suggest using `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is that if anyone wants to try out your tables on a sandbox instance, they have to painstakingly recreate the table by guessing at your columns and indexes. It's possible to piece together something resembling your tale from your SHOW INDEXES, but it takes too much work and I can't be sure it's correct. I am not going to spend time doing that. Good luck!

Comment: I totally understand Bill, I've now added the create table statements.

Comment: What happens to query performance if you omit the  `GROUP BY` clause? (I know it doesn't yield the result you want; the point is to figure out whether `GROUP BY ... LIMIT...` is soaking up a lot of time.)

Comment: Can you explain what you want  a little better? `COUNT(a.id)` in a query doing `a LEFT JOIN b` is a little strange. It counts matching rows from `b`, and counts `1` for every row in `a` without a matching row in `b`. Is that what you want? to me it sounds like the kind of thing that's hard to explain to users. Perfection in that `COUNT` operation is critical, because you use it later for the  `GROUP BY ... LIMIT ...` operation.

Comment: If I omit the `GROUP BY` and `LIMIT`, the query comes back in 1.7 seconds when it usually takes 70 seconds. The purpose of the query is to find all sources for an analytics row and show how many transactions were successful for that source. Essentially a conversion rate for each source.

Comment: What are the PK/FK relations of both tables? There's a `user_id` in both tables, is there a relation, i.e. is it possible to add `analytics.user_id = transactions.user_id`?

Comment: There is no PK/FK relationship on these two tables at all. Also adding `analytics.user_id = transactions.user_id` would change the query output as we still want a count of all the sources that don't have a transaction associated with it.

Comment: There might be no *physically* implemented (i.e. in DDL) relationship, but the tables must be *logically* related, otherwise how would you how to join? If the user_id for the same analytics.id & transactions.analytics is the same you can add it to the join (and apply the aggregation before the join)

Comment: @DavidButtrick - I think that playing with disk arrangement is unnecessary in today's caching schemes; it may even hurt performance.

Comment: How many rows do you get without `LIMIT`? And How many rows without `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Hi @abs.  Your use of sum() to effectively count the completed transactions will force the creation of a temp file to evaluate every row to determine the value to use in the calculation.  You should consider offloading this to a "pre-calculated" value.  Two questions, though. 1) what is the cardinality? Get this from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS for both tables and each of the columns. This could suggest how to reorganize the query. 2) Why don't you use 'date?' Most use-cases would allow this for bounding the answer set. It'd have to be in the index, of course.

Comment: @Abs try these methods : http://rextester.com/JCOP97565

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would create the following indexes (b-tree indexes):

```
analytics(user_id, source, id) 
transactions(analytics, status)
```

This is different from Gordon's suggestion.

**The order of columns in the index is important.**

You filter by specific `analytics.user_id`, so this field has to be the first in the index.
Then you group by `analytics.source`. To avoid sorting by `source` this should be the next field of the index. You also reference `analytics.id`, so it is better to have this field as part of the index, put it last. Is MySQL capable of reading just the index and not touching the table? I don't know, but it is rather easy to test.

Index on `transactions` has to start with `analytics`, because it would be used in the `JOIN`. We also need `status`.

```
SELECT 
    analytics.source AS referrer, 
    COUNT(analytics.id) AS frequency, 
    SUM(IF(transactions.status = 'COMPLETED', 1, 0)) AS sales
FROM analytics
LEFT JOIN transactions ON analytics.id = transactions.analytics
WHERE analytics.user_id = 52094 
GROUP BY analytics.source 
ORDER BY frequency DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I would be interested to see what the performance gains are from this suggestion - this seems like a great suggestion.

Comment: @DavidCa1226, yes, I'm curious too. Often appropriate indexes is the most powerful way to tune the query. Only after you confirm that the covering index doesn't help as expected you start looking into the execution plan details and trying to adjust the query, so that the optimiser uses the index as expected.

Answer (score 7):

First some analysis...

```
SELECT  a.source AS referrer,
        COUNT(*) AS frequency,  -- See question below
        SUM(t.status = 'COMPLETED') AS sales
    FROM  analytics AS a
    LEFT JOIN  transactions AS t  ON a.id = t.analytics AS a
    WHERE  a.user_id = 52094
    GROUP BY  a.source
    ORDER BY  frequency DESC
    LIMIT  10
```

If the mapping from `a` to `t` is "one-to-many", then you need to consider whether the `COUNT` and `SUM` have the correct values or inflated values.  As the query stands, they are "inflated".  The `JOIN` occurs *before* the aggregation, so you are counting the number of transactions and how many were completed.  I'll assume that is desired.

Note:  The usual pattern is `COUNT(*)`; saying `COUNT(x)` implies checking `x` for being `NULL`.  I suspect that check is not needed?

This index handles the `WHERE` and is "covering":

```
 analytics:  INDEX(user_id, source, id)   -- user_id first

 transactions:  INDEX(analytics, status)  -- in this order
```

The `GROUP BY` may or may not require a 'sort'.  The `ORDER BY`, being different than the `GROUP BY`, definitely will need a sort.  And the entire grouped set of rows will need to be sorted; there is no shortcut for the `LIMIT`.

Normally, Summary tables are date-oriented.  That is, the `PRIMARY KEY` includes a 'date' and some other dimensions.  Perhaps, keying by date and user_id would make sense?  How many transactions per day does the average user have?  If at least 10, then let's consider a Summary table.  Also, it is important not to be `UPDATEing` or `DELETEing` old records.  [*More*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)

I would probably have

```
user_id ...,
source ...,
dy DATE ...,
status ...,
freq      MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
status_ct MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, status, source, dy)
```

Then the query becomes

```
SELECT  source AS referrer,
        SUM(freq) AS frequency,
        SUM(status_ct) AS completed_sales
    FROM  Summary
    WHERE  user_id = 52094
      AND  status = 'COMPLETED'
    GROUP BY source
    ORDER BY  frequency DESC
    LIMIT  10
```

The speed comes from many factors

- Smaller table (fewer rows to look at)
- No `JOIN`
- More useful index

(It still needs the extra sort.)

Even without the summary table, there may be some speedups...

- How big are the tables?  How big is `innodb_buffer_pool_size?
- `Normalizing` some of the strings that are both bulky and repetitive could make that table not I/O-bound.
- This is awful:  `KEY (transaction_id(191))`; See [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes) for 5 ways to fix it.
- IP addresses do not need 255 bytes, nor `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.  (39) and ascii are sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for the useful analytics Rick! I will go through each and see which i can implement without worrying too much.

Comment: @Abs - and possibly experiment.  Pretty easy to copy a table for playing with:  `CREATE TABLE copy LIKE live;  INSERT INTO copy SELECT * FROM live;`

Answer (score 6):

For this query:

```
SELECT a.source AS referrer, 
       COUNT(*) AS frequency, 
       SUM( t.status = 'COMPLETED' ) AS sales
FROM analytics a LEFT JOIN
     transactions t
     ON a.id = t.analytics
WHERE a.user_id = 52094 
GROUP BY a.source 
ORDER BY frequency DESC 
LIMIT 10 ;
```

You want an index on `analytics(user_id, id, source)` and `transactions(analytics, status)`.

Comment: I should've mentioned I have indexes but not composite indexes, the above are composite indexes right? Running it now, might take some time to apply these  to the large test tables.

Comment: I added the indexes and this didn't make much of a difference unfortunately, it still takes 70 seconds to execute.

Comment: `176200` match the `user_id` on the analytics table.

Comment: 70 seconds seems like a long time, but it will take some time for the `group by`.

Comment: @Abs - Please provide (1) `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and (2) updated `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Those indexes should have helped.

Comment: @Abs . . . If 176,200 match the `user_id` in the `analytics` table, then millions might be matching from the `transactions` table.  You are processing a lot of data.  I don't think you'll be able to get better performance.  If that is necessary for your application, you might need to maintain summary tables or switch to a different database engine.

Comment: @Abs Make sure you added exactly the indexes that Gordon proposed. Assuming the indexes `*_gordon` that you listed in your question are the ones you tried, you seem to have added the columns in the wrong order - `analytics(id, user_id, source)` instead of `analytics(user_id, id, source)` and `transactions(status, analytics)` instead of `transactions(analytics, status)`.

Answer (score 4):

Try below and let me know if this helps.

```
SELECT 
    analytics.source AS referrer, 
    COUNT(analytics.id) AS frequency, 
    SUM(IF(transactions.status = 'COMPLETED', 1, 0)) AS sales
FROM (SELECT * FROM analytics where user_id = 52094) analytics
LEFT JOIN (SELECT analytics, status from transactions where analytics = 52094) transactions ON analytics.id = transactions.analytics
GROUP BY analytics.source 
ORDER BY frequency DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this took roughly 70 seconds too.

Comment: Hmm, try add to replace the LEFT JOIN with this:
LEFT JOIN transactions ON analytics.id = transactions.analytics and transactions.analytics = 52094

Comment: or...:
LEFT JOIN (SELECT transactions.status from transactions where analytics = 52094) transactions ON analytics.id = transactions.analytics

Comment: I tried the `LEFT JOIN transactions ON analytics.id = transactions.analytics and transactions.analytics = 52094` still roughly 70 seconds. And the last query isn't valid?

Comment: Damnit..i made a mistake, try this one:
LEFT JOIN (SELECT analytics, status from transactions where analytics = 52094) transactions ON analytics.id = transactions.analytics

Comment: No worries but it still takes around 65 seconds. I think you shaved of 5 seconds! But still very slow. I think the only option left is a summary table that gets updated periodically *sigh*.

Comment: Great! 7% performance increase! I am sorry I couldn't do more. I will update my original post, to include the "solution", otherwise a Summary table is not a bad idea, I had to do that several times.

Comment: Done, changed the original post, feel free to upvote it.

Comment: @VincentRye - Changing a `JOIN` into a subquery without any semantic change will _not_ speed things up in MySQL.

Comment: @Rick James - Apparently it id. The subquery has a where statement in it. It could also have been written without a subquery and added an additional where on the join itself. Either should work fine.

Comment: @VincentRye, your query produces completely different result than original query. Why do you filter `transactions` table with `analytics = 52094`? Original filter is on `analytics.user_id`. `transactions.analytics` is not related to `analytics.user_id` in any way, but you filter it with the same value. `transactions.analytics` is related to `analytics.id`, not `analytics.user_id`.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov you are completely right. I totally mis-read that original post. Take out the sub query in the LEFT JOIN, that's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Could you try below Approach:

```html
SELECT 
    analytics.source AS referrer, 
    COUNT(analytics.id) AS frequency, 
    SUM(sales) AS sales
FROM analytics
LEFT JOIN(
 SELECT transactions.Analytics, (CASE WHEN transactions.status = 'COMPLETED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sales
 FROM analytics INNER JOIN transactions ON analytics.id = transactions.analytics
) Tra
ON analytics.id = Tra.analytics
WHERE analytics.user_id = 52094 
GROUP BY analytics.source 
ORDER BY frequency DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 3):

This query potentially joins millions of `analytics` records with `transactions` records and calculates the sum (including the status check) on millions of records.
If we could first apply the `LIMIT 10` and then do the join and calculate the sum, we could speed up the query.
Unfortunately, we need the `analytics.id` for the join, which gets lost after applying the `GROUP BY`. But maybe `analytics.source` is selective enough to boost the query anyway.

My Idea is therefore to calculate the frequencies, limit by them, to return the `analytics.source` and `frequency` in a subquery and to use this result to filter the `analytics` in the main query, which then does the rest of the joins and calculations on a hopefully much reduced number of records.

Minimal subquery (note: no join, no sum, returns 10 records):

```
SELECT
    source,
    COUNT(id) AS frequency
FROM analytics
WHERE user_id = 52094
GROUP BY source
ORDER BY frequency DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

The full query using the above query as subquery `x`:

```
SELECT
    x.source AS referrer,
    x.frequency,
    SUM(IF(t.status = 'COMPLETED', 1, 0)) AS sales
FROM
    (<subquery here>) x
    INNER JOIN analytics a
       ON x.source = a.source  -- This reduces the number of records
    LEFT JOIN transactions t
       ON a.id = t.analytics
WHERE a.user_id = 52094      -- We could have several users per source
GROUP BY x.source, x.frequency
ORDER BY x.frequency DESC
```

If this does not yield the expected performance boost, this could be due to MySQL applying the joins in an unexpected order. As explained here ["Is there a way to force MySQL execution order?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3458481/880990), you could replace the join by `STRAIGHT_JOIN` in this case.

Comment: @Abs: Did my suggested changes speed up your query?

Answer (score 2):

I would try subquery:

```
SELECT a.source AS referrer, 
       COUNT(*) AS frequency,
       SUM((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM transactions t 
        WHERE a.id = t.analytics AND t.status = 'COMPLETED')) AS sales
FROM analytics a
WHERE a.user_id = 52094 
GROUP BY a.source
ORDER BY frequency DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

Plus indexes exactly as @Gordon's answer: analytics(user_id, id, source) and  transactions(analytics, status).

Comment: I'm not sure this query will run. You are using analytics.id in select, but you don't group by it.

Comment: @AlexandrKapshuk Of course it will run: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qzk3NqwaYDHENvQpp4bNat/0. But if you we want to be strict I should wrap subquery with `MIN`

Comment: in case there are several different `id` with the same `source` in `analytics` table, the query won't sum over all `id`. I think it can be corrected by using `sum` instead of `min`. Didn't know you can do that in MySQL!

Comment: The select subquery will execute once for every `analytics` result row. This may seem fast for values of `user_id` with few results but will be slow for values where there are many result rows.

Answer (score 2):

Only Problem I find in your query is

```
GROUP BY analytics.source 
ORDER BY frequency DESC
```

because of this query is doing filesort using temporary table.

One way to avoid this is by creating another table like

```
CREATE TABLE `analytics_aggr` (
  `source` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `frequency` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sales` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `sales` (`sales`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`
```

insert data into analytics_aggr using below query

```
insert into analytics_aggr SELECT 
    analytics.source AS referrer, 
    COUNT(analytics.id) AS frequency, 
    SUM(IF(transactions.status = 'COMPLETED', 1, 0)) AS sales
    FROM analytics
    LEFT JOIN transactions ON analytics.id = transactions.analytics
    WHERE analytics.user_id = 52094 
    GROUP BY analytics.source 
    ORDER BY null
```

Now you can easily get you data using

```
select * from analytics_aggr order by sales desc
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    a.source AS referrer, 
    COUNT(a.id) AS frequency, 
    SUM(t.sales) AS sales
FROM (Select id, source From analytics Where user_id = 52094) a
LEFT JOIN (Select analytics, case when status = 'COMPLETED' Then 1 else 0 end as sales 
           From transactions) t ON a.id = t.analytics
GROUP BY a.source 
ORDER BY frequency DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

I'm proposing this because you said "they are massive table" but this sql using very few columns only. In this case if we use inline view with require columns only then it will be good

Note: memory also will play important role here. So confirm the memory before decide the inline view

Answer (score 2):

I would try to separate querying from the two tables. Since you need only top 10 `source`s, I would get them first and then query from `transactions` the `sales` column:

```
SELECT  source as referrer
        ,frequency
        ,(select count(*) 
          from   transactions t  
          where  t.analytics in (select distinct id 
                                 from   analytics 
                                 where  user_id = 52094
                                        and source = by_frequency.source) 
                 and status = 'completed'
         ) as sales
from    (SELECT analytics.source
                ,count(*) as frequency
        from    analytics 
        where   analytics.user_id = 52094
        group by analytics.source
        order by frequency desc
        limit 10
        ) by_frequency
```

It may be also faster without the `distinct`

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming the predicate, user_id = 52094, is for illustration purpose and in application, the selected user_id is a variable.

I also assume that ACID property is not very important here.

(1) Therefore, I will maintain two replica tables with only the necessary fields (it is similar to the indices Vladimir had suggested above) using a utility table.

```
CREATE TABLE mv_anal (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` varchar(45),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE mv_trans (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `analytics` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE util (
  last_updated_anal int (11) NOT NULL,
  last_updated_trans int (11) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO util (0, 0);
```

The gain here is that we will be reading a relatively smaller projections of the original tables -- hopefully, OS level and DB level caches work and they aren't read from slower secondary storage but from faster RAM. **This can be a very great gain.**

Here is how I updated the two tables (the below is a transaction run by a cron) :

```
-- TRANSACTION STARTS -- 

INSERT INTO mv_trans 
SELECT id, IF (status = 'COMPLETE', 1, 0) AS status, analysis 
FROM transactions JOIN util
ON util.last_updated_trans <= transactions.id

UPDATE util
SET last_updated_trans = sub.m
FROM (SELECT MAX (id) AS m FROM mv_trans) sub;

-- TRANSACTION COMMITS -- 

-- similar transaction for mv_anal.
```

(2) Now, I will tackle the selectivity to reduce sequential scan time. I will have to build a b-tree index on user_id, source and id (in this sequence) on mv_anal.

Note: the above can be achieved by just creating index on analytics table but building such an index requires reading big table with 60M rows. My method requires the index building to read only very thin table. Thus, we can rebuild the btree more frequently (to counter the skew problem as the table is append-only).

This is how I make sure **the high selectivity is achieved when querying** and to counter skewing btree problem.

(3) In PostgreSQL, WITH subqueries are always materialized. I hope similarly for MySQL. Therefore, as the last mile of optimization:

```
WITH sub_anal AS (
  SELECT user_id, source AS referrer, COUNT (id) AS frequency
  FROM mv_anal
  WHERE user_id = 52094
  GROUP BY user_id, source
  ORDER BY COUNT (id) DESC
  LIMIT 10
)
SELECT sa.referrer, sa.frequency, SUM (status) AS sales
FROM sub_anal AS sa 
JOIN mv_anal anal 
ON sa.referrer = anal.source AND sa.user_id = anal.user_id
JOIN mv_trans AS trans
ON anal.id = trans.analytics
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party. I think you'll need to load one index into MySQL's cache. The NLJ is probably killing performance. Here's how I see it:

**The Path**

Your query is simple. It has two tables and the "path" is very clear:

- The optimizer should plan on reading the `analytics` table first.
- The optimizer should plan on reading the `transactions` table second. This is because you are using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. No much discussion on this one.
- Besides, the `analytics` table is 60 million rows and the best path should filter rows as soon as possible on this one.

**The Access**

Once the path is clear, you need to decide if you want to use an Index Access or a Table Access. Both have pros and cons. However, you want to improve the `SELECT` performance:

- You should choose Index Access.
- Avoid hybrid access. Therefore, you should avoid any Table Access (fetches) at all cost. Translation: place all the participating columns in indexes.

**The Filtering**

Again, you want high performance for the `SELECT`. Therefore:

- You should perform the filtering at the index level, not at the table level.

**Row Aggregation**

After filtering, the next step is to aggregate rows by `GROUP BY analytics.source`. This can be improved by placing the `source` column as the first column in the index.

**Optimal Indexes for Path, Access, Filtering, and Aggregation**

Considering all the above, you should include all mentioned columns into indexes. The following indexes should improve the response time:

```
create index ix1_analytics on analytics (user_id, source, id);

create index ix2_transactions on transactions (analytics, status);
```

These indexes fulfill the "path", the "access", and the "filtering" strategies decribed above.

**The Index Cache**

Finally -- and this is critical -- load the secondary index into MySQL's memory cache. MySQL is performing a NLJ (Nested Loop Join) -- a 'ref' in MySQL lingo -- and needs to access the second one randomly nearly 200k times.

Unfortunately, I don't know for sure how to load the index into MySQL's cache. The use of `FORCE` may work, as in:

```
SELECT 
    analytics.source AS referrer, 
    COUNT(analytics.id) AS frequency, 
    SUM(IF(transactions.status = 'COMPLETED', 1, 0)) AS sales
FROM analytics
LEFT JOIN transactions FORCE index (ix2_transactions)
  ON analytics.id = transactions.analytics
WHERE analytics.user_id = 52094 
GROUP BY analytics.source 
ORDER BY frequency DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Make sure you have enough cache space. Here's a short question/answer to figure out: [How to figure out if mysql index fits entirely in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748629/how-to-figure-out-if-mysql-index-fits-entirely-in-memory)

Good luck! Oh, and post the results.

Comment: "`LOAD INDEX INTO CACHE` is used only for `MyISAM` tables" - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-index.html

Comment: You're right, this worked for MyISAM. However, it's still critical to load the secondary index `ix2_transactions` into the cache. `FORCE` may help here, but I'm not sure. If it can't be loaded, I don't see how the speed can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

This question has definitely received a lot of attention so I'm sure all obvious solutions have been tried. I did not see something that addresses the `LEFT JOIN` in the query, though.

I have noticed that `LEFT JOIN` statements usually force query planners into hash join which are fast for a small number of results, but terribly slow for a large number of results. As noted in @Rick James' answer, since the join in the original query is on the identity field `analytics.id`, this will generate large number of results. A hash join will yield terrible performance results. The suggestion below addresses this below without any schema or processing changes.

Since the aggregation is by `analytics.source`, I would try a query that creates separate aggregations for frequency by source and sales by source and defers the left join until after aggregation is complete. This should allow the indexes to be used best (typically this is a merge join for large data sets).

Here is my suggestion:

```
SELECT t1.source AS referrer, t1.frequency, t2.sales
FROM (
  -- Frequency by source
  SELECT a.source, COUNT(a.id) AS frequency
  FROM analytics a
  WHERE a.user_id=52094
  GROUP BY a.source
) t1
LEFT JOIN (
  -- Sales by source
  SELECT a.source,
    SUM(IF(t.status = 'COMPLETED', 1, 0)) AS sales
  FROM analytics a
  JOIN transactions t
  WHERE a.id = t.analytics
    AND t.status = 'COMPLETED'
    AND a.user_id=52094
  GROUP by a.source
) t2
  ON t1.source = t2.source
ORDER BY frequency DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hash-join does not exist in MySQL.  (And Hash Indexes do not exist, with one exception, in MySQL.)

Comment: @RickJames - The correct MySQL terminology may be [Nested Loop joins](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/nested-loop-joins.html)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  Actually (as I understand it) NLJ (without buffering) uses BTree and has existed in MySQL since day 1.  BNL (Block NLJ) uses a "join buffer" to load all the data that will be joined to; then uses (presumably) a specially built Hash index.  InnoDB has no permanent Hash indexes.

Comment: Most of my low-level query optimization exp is with MS SQL, but the core DB principles are universal. MySQL join types are in [sql_select.h](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.3/sql/sql_select.h#L190). There are several ways inner/outer joins are performed by the query engine but the two main types as I understand them are lookup/loop joins that work well when the number of rows between tables is very different (ie. 1:100) and merge joins which order the rows prior to joining which work well for two high cardinality, high row count tables. The later is better for many rows (this case).